# Post iOS 10 upgrade scanForPeripheralsWithServices not discovering any device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios10, ios-bluetooth

Upgraded iPhone 6+ to version iOS 10. 
on call of scanForPeripheralsWithServices with list of service Ids not getting any callback centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI

While on iOS 9, same code is working fine.

on call of scanForPeripheralsWithServices with nil (service IDs) it work in foreground but
in background, the scanning is not working in both the case  with service Ids and without service Ids.

Comment: If you put nil in the parameters of `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options`, do you find your devices? What options did you put? If set to `nil`, are the services advertised by the peripherals and found by your `centralManager` are the same (could it be a case sensitive issue with the NSString conversion?)

Comment: Putting nil in the parameters of scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options, work while app is in foreground but didn't work when app is in background.

Comment: Can you add your code to your question. I'd like to see how you set up your list of UUID's and make the call. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. 

I am able to resolve the issue

_What went wrong ?_
I was using NSUUID instead of CBUUID.  (But for upto ios 9 it was working fine).


`[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:DANLAW_SERVICE_UUID], nil] options:nil];`

After replacing NSUUID with CBUUID all working well.

`[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DANLAW_SERVICE_UUID], nil] options:nil];`

Comment: It looks like not scanning in the background when using nil as the service list is by design ... the documentation for `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` says background scanning requires a specific service list.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to figure this out for days. And just found the answer, looks like you have too, so posting it here just incase somebody stumbles across this thread and misses your comment.

iOS 9 allowed you to implicitly cast your `NSUUID` to a `CBUUID` - this clearly is not allowed in iOS10.

You can use the method `[CBUUID UUIDWithNSUUID:anNSUUID]` when initialising a scan with `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with passing an empty array, it did filter based on the *CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey* option. I have not tested background scan yet but I am hopeful it will work.

```
NSArray *uuids = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0"]];
[self.cm scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[]
                                options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES),
                                    CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey:uuids}];
```

My guess is this is an apple bug and it will be fixed in an update.

Comment: passing an empty array, it did filter based on the CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey option.

Comment: passing an empty array, it did filter based on the CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey option. Did not work for me. In both case app was not able to discover the device.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 10.1,this issue happend again.

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:AUUID], nil] options:nil];
```

The scanning is not working in background.

My peripheral devices:
iPhone 6 , iOS 10.1
iPad mini 2 , iOS 10.0.2

Central device
iPhone 5S , iOS 9.3.5

and both peripheral devices in background, iPhone 5S only detected that iPad mini 2.

Comment: With iOS 10.1 beta i didn't  face  issue for scanning in background. Will chck with iOS 10.1 and update.

Comment: For me  scanning is working in background with iOS 10.1.
 @user3221820 can u add your code ?
Also have you added NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription in Info plist.

Comment: NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
    CBUUID *uuid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"6476B13F-4486-4723-AD1E-0B66B50B765B"];
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[uuid] options:options];

And I use iPhone6 to advertising in background.

Comment: And I have added NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription in info plist. It is working fine in iOS 10.0.2 on my iPad mini 2, but not sure on my iPhone 6 with iOS 10.0.2, because I already upgrade it to 10.1

Comment: For me I was able to discover if the searched device (iOS 10.1) had either the app opened or it was locked, but not if the device was unlocked with the app in the background. In that case it would only be found if I searched for all services.